# JavaScript Can't get text to change on click in JQuery Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having issues on pages like this: https://staging.hellodadventures.com/event/clippers-scifest-socal/

Where I have a More Info button and the idea is when clicked upon the "+ More Info" text should change, but it's not. I'm basing it on this [fiddle I found](http://jsfiddle.net/V4u5X/2/), but if you check out my example, nothing changes.

Here's what I have in my PHP:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <p>+ More Info</p>
        <div><p>Text goes here</p></div>
</div>
```

And then my JS:

```
//change button text on click
jQuery('.ui-accordion-header').click(function(){
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    $this.toggleClass('ui-accordion-header');
    if($this.hasClass('ui-accordion-header')){
        $this.text('+ More Info');
    } else {
        $this.text('- Less Info');
    }
});
```

I changed $ from the example to jQuery since it's a WordPress site.

Any ideas why this isn't changing on click? I did try using the button element as well, but no changes.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery('.ui-accordion-header') is trying to grab an element with the class "ui-accordion-header"

`<p class="ui-accordion-header">+ More Info</p>` should work.